# Objective of Get Set

Tags: c#

Is the only objective of get set is to access a private/protected variable, without breaking concept of encapsulation?
Because as per my findings I cannot see any other use of get set property.

Comment: [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

No - that's *usually* what it does, but accessors can perform whatever calculation you want. Fundamentally, a property is meant to provide access to logical state of a value - but that *logical* state doesn't have to translate to a single field of the same type in the *implementation*.

As an example, my Noda Time project has a `LocalDate` type with properties of `Year`, `Month` and `Day`. In v1, the backing field for `LocalDate` was a `LocalDateTime` which itself had a backing field representing the number of ticks since the Unix epoch, and the year/month/day was calculated from that.

In v2, there's an entirely different implementation, with a backing field packing the year/month/day values into a single `long` field but with much less calculation required.

Callers won't need to know there's been any change, but in *neither* version was the getter just returning the value of the backing field. The implementation detail was hidden from them.

Properties with both getters and setters are more likely to be backed by a simple field - but there, the setter may well perform validation checks, and the getter may be lazy too.

Comment: You're not only very good in answering, typing also. 12 lines in 3 minutes ;)

Comment: Any difference by getting a value from `property` instead of a `method` call? like `public int day {get{return _day;}}` or `public int day(){return _day;}`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: It's more pleasant to call properties that methods, basically. But ultimately a property *is* just one or two methods, with metadata connecting them.

Comment: apart from `pleasant` is there any advantage over `performance`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: No - as I say, properties *are* just methods, so why would they be faster than methods?

Answer (score 1):

Another use is you can have custom logic. For instance, when setting a variable, you can check to make sure it is in bounds.

For example, if you have a class Fraction, with numerator and denominator, when setting the denominator, you would want to check that it is not zero.